# wit.ai + Jump from one story to another

Tags: wit.ai

Using bookmarks to jump from any point in the story is a very useful feature. But can we use Jump and bookmark to jump from one story to another? It seems to be possible as the bookmarks drop-down shows all the bookmarks across the stories not just the bookmarks within the story. But my doubt is how will it recognize the intent of the new story to be executed.

Any example of wit application would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

I answered with a homemade solution here [wit.ai - unrecognised user entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331967/wit-ai-unrecognised-user-entries/40382873#40382873)

Essentially, you can create an action call "jumpTo[Insert-Your-Story-Name]Story". On your side, this action "emulates" the fact that the users sent a pre-determined message that will triggered your another story.

It works, but I don't know if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try this solution.